# Plotting a function with an argument in degrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pst-plot

I want to plot a function. The function is, F is proportional to x/cos(x). Here x is rotation in degree and F is the force. I have to plot the graph where the x axis will be from 0 to 70 degree and the y axis will be linear value 0 to 5.

I am not able to find any option to draw graphs where x axis is with rotational degree.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Please show us your effort in form of small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. For example, `pgfplots` has instruction `trig format plots=deg`.

Comment: what does `F is proportional to x/cos(x)` mean? `F =k* x/cos(x)` for some k? You can draw with TikZ `\draw plot[domain=0:70] F(\x) ...`

Comment: I was using these codes:                                                                            \begin{document}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
trig format plots=deg
domain=0:70,
samples=50,
no marks,
xticklabels={0$\deg$,10$\deg$,20$\deg$,30$\deg$,40$\deg$,50$\deg$,60$\deg$,70$\deg$},
xtick={deg(0),deg(10),deg(20),deg(30),deg(40),deg(50),deg(60),deg(70)},
x post scale = 5
]
\addplot {deg(x)/cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: Yes , F=l/c .x/cos(x) , where l/c is constant